# Java socket: Connection reset

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have browsed, searched ... and nothing sparkles to my mind!

I am running a chat type service between a server and an Android app. The client connects, the server registers the socket, and every 10 minutes the server sends to all connected devices a message.

My problem is that randomly I have a connection reset exception. I can not trace back when the problem occurs.

**My server side code is:**

```
final public class ChatRoomService {
    private final static String AUTHENTICATE = "AUTHENTICATE";
    private final static String BROADCAST = "BROADCAST";
    private final static String DISCONNECT = "DISCONNECT";
    private final static String OK = "OK";
    private final static String NOK = "NK";

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ChatRoomService.class);

    private ServerSocket listener = null;

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    @Inject
    private PlayerManager playerManager;
    PlayerManager getPlayerManager() {
        return playerManager;
    }

    private static HashSet<ChatRoomConnection> connections = new HashSet<ChatRoomConnection>();
    public void addConnection(ChatRoomConnection c) {
        synchronized(connections) {
            connections.add(c);
        }
    }
    public void removeConnection(ChatRoomConnection c) {
        synchronized(connections) {
            connections.remove(c);
        }
    }

    public void startListeningToChatRoomConnection() throws IOException {
        listener = new ServerSocket(9010);

        try {
            LOGGER.infof("startListening - Start listening on port %s", 9010);
            while (true) {
                ChatRoomConnection connection = new ChatRoomConnection(listener.accept(), this);
                addConnection(connection);
                connection.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (!listener.isClosed())
                LOGGER.errorf("listenToChatRoomConnection - Connection lost during connection: %s", e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (listener != null && !listener.isClosed()) {
                LOGGER.infof("listenToChatRoomConnection - Stop listening");
                listener.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopListeningToChatRoomConnection() throws IOException {
        if (!listener.isClosed()) {
            LOGGER.infof("stopListeningToChatRoomConnection - Stop listening");

            listener.close();
            listener = null;

            // Closing all sockets
            for (ChatRoomConnection connection : connections) {
                    connection.close();
            }
            // Clear up the connections list
            synchronized (connections) {
                connections.clear();
            }
        }
    }

    public void broadcastToChatRoomClients(Object message) {
        synchronized (connections) {
            // Log
            LOGGER.debugf("Broadcast ChatRoom: %s - %s", 
                    connections.size(),
                    message.toString());

            for (ChatRoomConnection connection : connections) {
                LOGGER.debugf("Broadcast ChatRoom to %s", connection.userName);
                connection.publish(message);
            }
        }
    }

    private ChatRoomService() {
    }

    private static class ChatRoomConnection extends Thread {
        private Socket socket;
        private BufferedReader readerFromClient;
        private PrintWriter writerToClient;
        public String userName;

        private ChatRoomService chatCService;

        ChatRoomConnection(Socket socket, ChatRoomService chatRoomService) {
            super("ChatRoomConnection");

            this.socket = socket;
            this.chatRoomService = chatRoomService;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                readerFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                writerToClient = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                // 1- Authenticate the Device/ Player
                writerToClient.println(ChatRoomService.AUTHENTICATE);   
                writerToClient.flush();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Request request = gson.fromJson(readerFromClient.readLine(), Request.class);
                if (chatRoomService.getPlayerManager().isPlayerSignedIn(request.getPlayerId(), request.getSignedInOn())) {
                    Player player = (Player) chatRoomService.getEntityManager().find(Player.class, request.getPlayerId());
                    userName = player.getUsername();
                    LOGGER.infof("listenToChatRoomConnection - Connection established with %s", userName);
                    writerToClient.println(ChatRoomService.OK); 
                    writerToClient.flush();
                    while (true)
                        if ((readerFromClient.readLine() == null) || 
                            (readerFromClient.readLine().startsWith(ChatRoomService.DISCONNECT)))
                        break;
                } else {
                    writerToClient.println(ChatRoomService.NOK);
                    writerToClient.flush();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.errorf("listenToChatRoomConnection - Error with %s: %s", userName, e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (!socket.isClosed()) {
                        LOGGER.infof("listenToChatRoomConnection - Connection closed by the client for %s", userName);
                        socket.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOGGER.errorf("listenToChatRoomConnection - Can not close socket: %s", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    chatRoomService.removeConnection(this);
                }
            }
        }

        public void publish(Object message) {
            if (!socket.isClosed()) {
                writerToClient.println(ChatRoomService.BROADCAST);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                writerToClient.println(gson.toJson(message));
            }
        }

        public void close() {
            writerToClient.println(ChatRoomService.DISCONNECT);
            try {
                LOGGER.infof("listenToChatRoomConnection - Connection closed by the server for %s", userName);
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.errorf("Error when trying to close a socket: %s", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**The device code is:**

```
public class ServerBroadcastManager {
    private static final String TAG = ServerBroadcastManager.class.getName();

    // Type of messages from the server
    static public String AUTHENTICATE = "AUTHENTICATE";
    static public String DISCONNECT = "DISCONNECT";
    static public String BROADCAST = "BROADCAST";
    static public String OK = "OK";
    static public String NOK = "NK";

    private int networkPort;
    private ServerBroadcastListener broadcastListener;
    private Socket networkSocket;

    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;

    public ServerBroadcastManager(Context context, ServerBroadcastListener listener, int port) {
    this.networkPort = port;
    this.broadcastListener = listener;
    }

    public void startListening(final Context context) {
    Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Make connection and initialize streams
            try {
                networkSocket = new Socket();
                networkSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(mydomain, networkPort), 30*1000);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        networkSocket.getInputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(networkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

                // Process all messages from server, according to the protocol.
                while (true) {
                    String line = in.readLine();
                    if (line.startsWith(ServerBroadcastManager.AUTHENTICATE)) {
                        Request request = formatAuthenticateRequest(context);
                        Gson requestGson = new Gson();          
                        out.println(requestGson.toJson(request));
                        out.flush();
                        // Waiting for confirmation back
                        line = in.readLine();
                        if (line.startsWith(ServerBroadcastManager.OK)) {
                        } else if (line.startsWith(ServerBroadcastManager.NOK)) {
                        }
                    } else if (line.startsWith(ServerBroadcastManager.BROADCAST)) {
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        LinkedHashMap<String,String> broadcast = gson.fromJson(in.readLine(), LinkedHashMap.class);
                        broadcastListener.processBroadcast(broadcast);
                    } else if (line.startsWith(ServerBroadcastManager.DISCONNECT)) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Can not resolve hostname");
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Connection Timed-out");

                broadcastListener.connectionFailed();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Connection raised on exception: " + e.getMessage());

                if (!networkSocket.isClosed()) {
                    broadcastListener.connectionLost();
                }
            }
        }           
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(run);
    thread.start();
}

public void stopListening() {
    try {
        if (networkSocket != null)
            networkSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Exception in stopListening: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private Request formatAuthenticateRequest(Context context) {
    Request request = new Request();
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Constants.USER_DETAILS, 0);

    request.setPlayerId(BigInteger.valueOf((settings.getLong(Constants.USER_DETAILS_PLAYERID, 0))));
    request.setSignedInOn(settings.getLong(Constants.USER_DETAILS_SIGNEDINON, 0));

    return request;
    }
}
```

My last resort might be to move my server to another location, and see if this could not be related to my broadband router. I have notice that some of my HTTP call do not reach the server as well, though port forwarding is properly in place.

Thanks.
David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find where in your source code the server sends a message every 10 minutes to all connected clients, but I have experienced connection reset exceptions while using long-lasting WebSocket connections. I solved that problem by making sure some data (ping-pong message) was send from the client every minute.

At the time I traced the problem to my home-router which simply closed all idle connections after 5 minutes, but firewalls can exhibit the same kind of behavior. Neither server or client will notice a closed connection until data is transmitted. This is especially nasty for the client if the client is expecting data from the server - that data will simply never arrive. Therefor, make it the responsibility of the client to check if a connection is still valid (and reconnect when needed).

Since the introduction of the ping-pong message from the client every minute, I have not seen connection reset exceptions.

Comment: Thanks! The good thing about the PING (which I did not want to implement) is that it is now the client that raises IOException so I can capture and potentially reconnect).

Would you know any good design pattern to reconnect? I am thinking of doing in the catch statement and restart a new handler but this seems odd to do so.

Comment: @l_ingenu Put your device code Runnable in a separate class/Object and put the code setting up a connection in a separate connect method of that runnable object. Call the connect method at the beginning of the run-method (as you do now) and call it again when a reconnect is needed. The only thing special about the reconnect is that you might have to cleanup some variables (like closing the socket and resetting the connection status) before calling the connect method again.